# content_script not running on GitHub when following links

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am writing a Chrome Extension mainly for Pull Requests on Github Enterprise and have ran into an issue. When the page is loaded via a refresh or direct entering of the url from your browser it runs, when it is ran from clicking a link within Github it does not.

For instance if you go to this page with [Pull Requests](https://github.com/MediaBrowser/Emby/pulls) and click into one of them it will not run. But if you refresh that same page it will run.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Github Sample",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Sample",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "<all_urls>",
        "http://github.com/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "https://github.com/*" ],
            "js": ["github.sample.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

github.sample.json

```
// ==UserScript==
// @author Jacob Schoen
// ==/UserScript==

alert("Extension has Ran");
```

To make this easier I have pushed this to [github](https://github.com/jkschoen/chrome_extension_sample).

Any ideas on how to address this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub site uses [jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) library (see [How to make github style page transitions by pjax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8013818)).

- Basically you only need to run the content script once and attach pjax event handlers inside [an injected `<script>` element code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) which will be reusing a `jQuery`or `$` variable of the site.

  - In those handlers you can send a message with `document.dispatchEvent` to your content script that will receive it in its `window.addEventListener("blabla", ...)`
  - or you can [allow the access to `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) on the github site in `manifest.json` so that page-injected code will be able to send a message that can be received by the extension in `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` listener.
- Alternatively you can use [chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onHistoryStateUpdated) in the background script but that will cause a warning during the installation that the extension can "Read your browsing history" which is a global permission unlike the content script solution.

Comment: Thanks I think this has me moving in the right direction now.

Comment: Thanks again, I was able to get it working with your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The working example I came up with, in case it helps anyone else.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Github Sample",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Sample",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs", "<all_urls>",
        "http://github.com/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "https://github.com/*" ],
            "js": ["github.sample.js"],
            "run_at": "document_idle"
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["inject.js"]
}
```

github.sample.js

```
// ==UserScript==
// @author Jacob Schoen
// ==/UserScript==

function myAlert() {
    alert("Extension has Ran");
}

window.addEventListener("pageLoadTransition", myAlert);

var s = document.createElement('script');
// TODO: add "script.js" to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('inject.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);

//still have to load this one for direct page loads
myAlert();
```

inject.js

```
$(document).on('pjax:success', function() {
  var evt=document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
    evt.initCustomEvent("pageLoadTransition", true, true, null);
    document.dispatchEvent(evt);
})
```

I also updated the Github repository with the working example.