# Listening for github.com PJAX events in Greasemonkey user script

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, greasemonkey, userscripts

A user script I'm working on successfully works on initially loaded GitHub page. Though it needs to be re-applied when GitHub is navigated with PJAX.

So I have to set up a listener for PJAX changes somehow and run `initialize` function again.

Patching `unsafeWindow.history.pushState` won't work because of Greasemonkey/Firefox security policy, it will throw

> Error: Permission denied to access object

I've tried to examine page scripts and hook to `ajaxComplete` event of `unsafeWindow.require('jquery')`, but the listener wasn't triggered (possibly because of the same security policy, but error console was empty).

Is there a better solution than `MutationObserver`/`DOMSubtreeModified` on PJAX container element?

The script is targeted at Firefox/Greasemonkey, but if it will be workable for Chrome/Tampermonkey, this won't hurt.

Comment: Add a listener for `"pjax:end"` event on `document`. Also looks like a duplicate of [How to make github style page transitions by pjax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8013818). FWIW a working [example](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/5982-github-images-as-icons) - as you can see a MutationObserver is also used because the site script overwrites the dynamic container *sometimes*.

Comment: @wOxxOm Good one, thanks a lot! `$(document).on('pjax:end', ...)` works on jQuery copy that was obtained with `@require`. Feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a listener for "pjax:end" event on document:

```
$(document).on('pjax:end', ...)
```

FWIW a working [example](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/5982-github-images-as-icons) in vanilla js. As you can see a MutationObserver is also used because the site script updates the dynamic container *sometimes* twice (discarding the first one completely), so, after the pjax:end handler completes, a MutationObserver handler is attached to detect removal of the file wrapper, in which case the processing is repeated:

```
document.addEventListener('pjax:end', pageChangedHandler);

function pageChangedHandler() {

    .......................

    var ovr = document.querySelector('include-fragment.file-wrap');
    if (ovr) {
        new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(m => {
                var removed = m.removedNodes[0];
                if (removed && removed.matches('.file-wrap')) {
                    this.disconnect();
                    pageChangedHandler();
                }
            });
        }).observe(ovr.parentNode, {childList:true});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. I've used to put debounce with 0-10 delay on MutationObserver/DOMSubtreeModified handlers, it was a good thing. But in my current script `pjax:end` alone is enough for now.